# Livewire 3 Component Input [Text] Update to Parent Variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire sub component where it loads under form

Form -> Input

Controller Snippet

```
class ListingEdit extends Component
{
    public $title; => Need to update this one
```

Here is the blade file in the form where I call component.input.input

```
<div class="mb-3">
    @livewire('component.input.input', ['value' => $title], key($title))
    <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('title')" class="mt-2" />
</div>
```

Here is Livewire Input Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Component\Input;

use Livewire\Component;

class Input extends Component
{
    public $value;
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.component.input.input',['title' => $this->value]);
    }
}
```

Here is the blade file of component.input.input

```
<input wire:model.live="value" {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }} {!! $attributes->merge(['class' => 'w-full border border-gray-300 p-2 focus:border-gray-500 focus:ring-gray-500 rounded-md shadow-sm']) !!}>
{{ $title ?? 'as' }}
```

I was trying to use [Reactive] under child component but it went

> Cannot mutate reactive prop [value] in component:
> [component.input.input]

I read the reactive can only be used to feed from parent -> child where I want to feed from child to parent

Comment: You should use Livewire events, to dispatch an event from your child component and listen to it on the parent component.
Read the docs here:
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation seems suitable for using the *Modelable* functionality:

The nested component called from the parent:

```html
<div class="mb-3">
   <x-livewire:component.input.input wire:model="title" :key="$title" />

    <!-- ...... -->
```

The child Input class:

```php
namespace App\Livewire\Component\Input;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\Modelable;

class Input extends Component
{
    #[Modelable]
    public $title;

    // the render is implicit
}
```

In the Input blade:

```html
<input wire:model.live="title">
```

Reference [here](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/nesting#binding-to-child-data-using-wiremodel)